# how to upload PDF files using angularjs or javascript

Tags: angularjs, file, pdf, upload, base64

I have a windows application using 8 angularjs . I need to upload a pdf file is converted to base64 and recorded in the application jsonStore . Only when I enter the application file closes without error in visual studio console. How can I fix this?

```
$scope.uploadComprovanteRenda = function (file) {
            OLog.info("upload do comprovante de renda");
            if (file && file.size) {
                if (file.type.indexOf("pdf") > -1 || file.type.indexOf("image") > -1) {
                    var files = [];
                    files.push(file);
                     OLog.info("[upload]Iniciando o processo de UploadBase64");
                    Upload.base64DataUrl(files).then(function(urls){
                         OLog.info("[upload]Entrando no metodo extrairBase64");
                        $scope.novoComprovanteRenda.documentos = extrairBase64(urls);
                        novoDocumento = criarDocumento(appConst.documento.tipo.COMPROVANTE_RENDA, $scope.novoComprovanteRenda.subTipoDocumento.renda, $scope.novoComprovanteRenda.documentos);
                        novoDocumento.tipo = file.type;
                        gravarImagensJsonStore(novoDocumento);
                        capturarImagemSucesso = capturarComprovanteRenda;
                        $scope.novoComprovanteRenda = {};
                        $scope.capturaRendaObrigatoria = false;
                    },function(error){
                         OLog.info("[upload]Erro ao executar o upload");
                         OLog.info("[upload]erro: " +error);
                    });
                }else{
                    WL.SimpleDialog.show(appConst.msg.MSG_ATENCAO, appConst.msg.MSG_TIPO_FORMATO_ARQUIVO, [{text: appConst.msg.MSG_OK}]);
                }
            }

        };
```

Comment: Can you translate the title to English please?

Comment: Canvas can not render base64 pdf in internet explorer